# Help to find this vanished ETH in failed transfer?

Tags: wallet-transfer

at a total loss as to how to track down where this ETH went.

I was sending from a wallet to another address.
The wallet itself shows 'completed' and viewing the transaction makes it look like the ETH has arrived at the new location.

The receiving address never got it, never showed pending, and looking at the ID on etherscan shows a fail.

However, it never returned to my original wallet (none of it, not the original amount minus the gas, none at all). I am sure the # of ETH did not change back to what it was. The transactions section of the wallet shows that ETH going out and that's all.

So I can't access it through my original wallet and it's not on the new location. It must be 'somewhere', right?

Luckily we are not talking a huge amount of money but still on principle this bothers me and want to know how this works if possible.

Here is the transaction id: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x15b08e781e4b33313e00ae33155189e9c090458d14dce5b9cfdc87349405fec3

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The transaction failed due to out of gas. The gas sent was consumed punitively. Etherscan says the value was about 2 cents, 0.0001008 Ether ($0.02). Sender balance will not revert to exactly what it was before because of that. Sender's history: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b46c7af311294a194ec530882fcc7c9bb284ba9

Comment: Thank you - however all of the ETH is gone, not the amount minus the gas, that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Did you see the transactions other than the one that failed? After the one you mentioned, there are 4 more. 1 failed, then 3 succeeded.

Comment: The two that failed were to the same place, then I sent larger ones to a different location once I saw they worked to that location. 
Inside the wallet itself, those failed transactions read like a success, contradicting what we see on etherscan. They read the same as the successful ones, just showing that amount of ether subtracted from the wallet. Very strange.

Comment: The total amount (minus gas) of the failed transactions don't seem to be accounted for anywhere, not in the original wallet or the new location where I successfully moved the ether. Unless there is a way to understand via looking at the transactions themselves in etherscan that did in fact happen and the wallet is just reporting wrong (which I can't figure out, total newbie)

Comment: When you say "the wallet is just reporting wrong," what do you mean? What is "the wallet"? In general, you can trust that Etherscan is telling you the right thing. The failed transactions should have had close to no effect on your balance (less than a 500th of an ether lost in gas costs). The subsequent three successful transactions emptied the original account.

Comment: "**The receiving address never got it**" - I think it did get it, and whoever owns that contract immediately withdrew the funds (by calling an `onlyOwner` function designated for this purpose).

Comment: The first address was a JAXX wallet -- the second another wallet (I own both) -- upon sending out of JAXX, the ETH decreased the full amount and never seems to have returned. 

JAXX reports that ETH as being sent -- it shows those transactions that we see as failed in etherscan as success in jaxx, with the full amount of the transaction subtracted. 

The receiving address I also own, and can see it never went into that wallet. I sent from coinbase to that wallet and it worked just fine, and can see that the exact same address was used. Hope that helps clarify. Thanks.

Comment: "The subsequent three successful transactions emptied the original account" -- here is a question, is there any way using the type of information you can see in etherscan to find out what that was? 

In the jaxx wallet itself, I saw the number decrease by the total amount of the failed transaction, and not return to the wallet. I'm wondering if it's possible the wallet software itself was just showing incorrect numbers but the blockchain itself could verify the actual amounts of these transactions start to finish including fail? Trying to use this experience to learn. Thanks.